# Why isn't my .exe from a Makefile printing from my second file?

Tags: c, build, makefile, printf, exe

I have an upcoming C project where I'm going to have to use makefiles so I made a quick example to get myself comfortable but ran into a bug.

I made one file that just prints "hello" and another that prints "world". Would someone be able to explain this?

I run the .exe and it only prints "hello". My makefile builds perfectly without any errors, I've been searching around and haven't seen any similar questions so any input would be appreciated.

The makefile:

```
mymalloc_test: mymalloc.o mymalloc_driver.o
    gcc -o mymalloc_test mymalloc.o mymalloc_driver.o   

mymalloc.o: mymalloc.c mymalloc.h
    gcc -c mymalloc.c

mymalloc_driver.o: mymalloc.h mymalloc_driver.c
    gcc -c mymalloc_driver.c
```

All i have in mymalloc and mymalloc_driver is 2 print statements.
ok here is the source I guess

mymalloc.c

```
#include "mymalloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("hello");

return 0;
}
```

mymalloc_driver.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mymalloc.h"

int test_main()
{
printf("world\n");

return 0;
}
```

and the empty header

```
#ifndef MYMALLOC_H_
#define MYMALLOC_H_

#endif /* MYMALLOC_H_ */
```

Comment: Have you *called* the function from another file which prints "World"? `Makefile` only allows you to modularize the code in to different files, it does not do anything more than that.

Comment: what do you mean? is only one of them run? like one is the "main"? is this where function pointers come into play?

Comment: The makefile is not the problem. We need to see the .c and .h files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All i have in mymalloc and mymalloc_driver is 2 print statements.
>   It doesn't work this way.

`Makefile` only allows you to modularize the code in to different files, it does not do anything more than that, the calling order of code statements is how you organize them in your `main()`function.

Your code should be organized as follows:
**mymalloc.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mymalloc.h"
#include "mymalloc_driver"

int main()  //The program execution starts here and continues further as statements are organized
{

    printf("\Hello");
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

**mymalloc_driver.c**

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
 #include "mymalloc_driver.h"

 void doSomething()
 {
    printf("World");
 }
```

**mymalloc_driver.h**

```
#ifndef MYMALLOC_DRIVER_H
#define MYMALLOC_DRIVER_H

void doSomething();

#endif
```

**mymalloc.h**

```
#ifndef MYMALLOC_H
#define MYMALLOC_H

//some declarations 

#endif
```

Comment: thank you very much. we went over this in class very quickly but you explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You define test_main() but never call it. Try adding it to main() like so:

```
int main()
{
printf("Hello ");
test_main();
return 0;
}
```

An important idea to grasp is that the function name `main()` is "**magic**" in C, it is the **only** function that gets called when your program runs. If you want any other functions to get called, you need to call them from `main()` (or from other functions that are themselves called by main, etc.)